# Using Select-Object in Powershell, how can I select only the part of a string I want on a per line basis?

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-3.0

Currently I have a script that will search a directory and fine all instances of the word "dummy". It will then output to a CSV the FileName, Path, LineNumber, Line to a file.

This Line contains a very standardized results like:

- Hi I am a dummy, who are you?
- Something dummy, blah blah?
- Lastly dummy, how is your day?

I am trying to find a way to output an additional column in my CSV that contains all characters before the "?" as well as all of the characters after "dummy,".

Resulting lines would be:

- who are you
- blah blah
- how is your day

I tried to use split but it keeps removing additional characters. Is it possible to find the index of "dummy," and "?" and then substring out the middle portion?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Code as it stands:

```
Write-Host "Hello, World!"

# path
$path = 'C:\Users\Documents\4_Testing\fe\*.ts'
# pattern to find dummy
$pattern = "dummy,"

Get-ChildItem -Recurse  -Path $path | Select-String -Pattern $pattern |
Select-Object FileName,Path,LineNumber,Line
,@{name='Function';expression={
    $_.Line.Split("dummy,")
}} |
Export-Csv 'C:\Users\User\Documents\4_Testing\Output1.csv' -NoTypeInformation

Write-Host "Complete"
```

Comment: What do you mean by "as well as all of the characters after"? "all characters before `?`" already contains all the characters after `dummy,`? Can you give an exact example of what (at least 1 of) the resulting column values should be?

Comment: I want "Hi I am a dummy, who are you?" to output to: "who are you"

Comment: Seems like you're looking for `$_.Line.Split(",")[1]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `-replace` [regex](/questions/tagged/regex) operator to replace the whole line with just the part between `dummy,` and `?`:

```
PS ~> 'Hi I am a dummy, who are you?' -replace '^.*dummy,\s*(.*)\?\s*$', '$1'
who are you
```

So your calculated property definition should like this:

```
@{Name = 'Function'; Expression = { $_.Line -replace '^.*dummy,\s*(.*)\?\s*$', '$1' }}
```

The pattern used above describes:

```
^         # start of string
 .*       # 0 or more of any character
 dummy,   # the literal substring `dummy,`
 \s*      # 0 or more whitespace characters
 (        # start of capture group
  .*      # 0 or more of any character
 )        # end capture group
 \?       # a literal question mark
 \s*      # 0 or more whitespace characters
$         # end of line/string
```

If you also want to remove everything after the first `?`, change the pattern slightly:

```
@{Name = 'Function'; Expression = { $_.Line -replace '^.*dummy,\s*(.*?)\?.*$', '$1' }}
```

Adding the metacharacter `?` to `.*` makes the subexpression *lazy*, meaning the regex engine tries to match *as few characters* as possible - meaning we'll only capture up until the *first* `?`.

Comment: This is very close -- I am sorry for not mentioning earlier but is there a way to handle additional text after the "?"? So if the line contains Hi I am a dummy, who are you? Hello? it would still only return: "who are you"

Running 'Hi I am a dummy, who are you? Hello?' -replace '^.*dummy,\s*(.*)\?\s*$', '$1'

Results in who are you? Hello

Comment: @user68288 I've updated the answer to cover this. For future reference, you'll have a better shot at getting useful answers if you include all relevant details in your question up front :-)